# Truncate file on Linux with c99

Tags: c, file, c99, truncate

I would like to open a file and set its size so that I can then use mmap to write to it.

I found that I can use function `truncate` or `ftruncate`. Unfortunately, when I include `<unistd.h>` I got error:

> error: implicit declaration of function ‘truncate’

I read on Internet that I should use gnu or something like that but this is for school project and we have to compile with `-std=c99`.

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Use `-std=gnu99` maybe no one notices :)

Comment: Add `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700` to the command line, or the equivalent `#define` before the first system `#include`, to activate POSIX (and X/Open) functions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler very well spotted, still a workaround though, I guess.

Comment: It's what you're supposed to do if you want to use the POSIX functions with a strict standard-conforming compiler.  Using  `-std=c99` makes GCC into a more nearly standard-conforming compiler.  Using `-std=gnu99` effectively enables a whole lot of extensions, including POSIX functions.  Another alternative is an explicit declaration of `truncate()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `-std=c99` the C library makes sure that the headers do not declare any symbols that are not reserved/are not defined in the **C standard library**. Since `ftruncate` does not belong to the C standard library, being a POSIX extension instead, it is not defined by default.

A POSIX program must, for maximal compatibility, [define the `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` feature test macro](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html), or `_XOPEN_SOURCE`, with appropriate values, before including the headers.

The feature test macros are listed conveniently on for example Linux manual pages; for [`ftruncate`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ftruncate.2.html) these would be:

```
   ftruncate():
       _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500
           || /* Since glibc 2.3.5: */ _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L
           || /* Glibc versions <= 2.19: */ _BSD_SOURCE
```

i.e. use

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500 // (or greater; current is 700)
#include <unistd.h>
```

or

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L // (or greater) 
#include <unistd.h>
```